# Can't call API controllers from referenced library on module

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, orchardcore

I created these web projects

- Orchard CMS
- Module
- Reusable API

Module references Reusable API, and it works fine on it's own

Added Module into CMS and enabled it

The problem is, it can't find the controllers on Reusable API from the CMS

---

Details:

[image]

CMS Startup.cs

```cs
  public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOrchardCms();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
          
             app.UseRouting();
            app.UseOrchardCore();

        }
    }
```

Module Startup.cs

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

Reusable API Startup.cs

```cs
   public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

ReusableAPI/Controllers/TestController.cs

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class TestController:ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Test()
        {
            return Ok("test");
        }
    }
```

If I run Module, I can call the API controller Test method with no problems
But, if I run the CMS, I can't call the API controller Test method, it gives me a 404 not found instead.

**However** - If I add controllers support on CMS/Startup.cs, the Reusable API works!

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddOrchardCms();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.UseOrchardCore();
        }
    }
```

[image]

**But** now I can't access the admin page
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi @The One, the error message means these Index actions in controllers are all used the same request url. How does these controllers' design?

Comment: Hi Rena, design is specific to Orchard Core https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore

Comment: You're not supposed to call UseRouting() or UseEndpoints() at all, as OrchardCore does the routing for you by its own convention.
Controllers or ApiControllers should therefore work just by using OrchardCore.